# Apache2 and Nginx on same server: how to make Nginx listen on certain IPs only, and let Apache2 listen on others?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, apache2

On Ubuntu 16.04, I need to run Nginx and Apache2 on the same server with multiple IP addresses. Nginx has to listen on certain IPs only, and Apache2 has to listen on other different IPs.

With Apache2, this is easy to achieve by configuring the desired IP addresses to be listened on in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`.
But how do I restrict Nginx to listen on just certain IPs only, without masking the others?

Let's assume I have 5 IPs: `192.0.2.1`, `192.0.2.2`, `192.0.2.3`, `192.0.2.4` and `192.0.2.5`.

- Nginx has to listen on `192.0.2.1`, `192.0.2.2` and `192.0.2.3`.
- Apache2 has to listen on `192.0.2.4` and `192.0.2.5`.
- The two servers will be listening on the ports 80 and 443 on their respective IPs.

Comment: You make nginx listen on only certain addresses by using the [listen](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) directive (go figure).  I'm voting to close this question because its based on opinion and doesn't contain a problem statement.

Comment: @yoonix, please could you give more details about where to use the 'listen' directive? I obviously have one 'listen' in each Nginx vhost, but what do I put in the Nginx default vhost config? At the moment, I have: 

server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server;

in the Nginx default config, but Apache2 is being masked. 
What is the equivalent of Apache2's port.config in Nginx?

Comment: @yoonix please read the original question above for the problem statement, I've tried to be clear and specific... Thank you for your understanding. :-)

Comment: You should click the link that @yoonix gave.

Comment: You need to add IP address to every `listen` directive in nginx. It is your choice what IP address to use for each `server` block.

Comment: This isn't related to a solution and I'm asking out of curiosity. Why do you need so many private IP addresses? Obviously it is up to you how many you use but I'm curious why you don't use 1 address.

Answer (score 1):

Both [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) and [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) have listen directives with pretty similar syntax regarding the binding address.

- Nginx: `listen address[:port] [default_server] [ssl] ...;` in `server {}` block
- Apache: `Listen [IP-address:]portnumber [protocol]` in server config. While your distribution may place the configuration in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, it's actually just included in the `apache2.conf`:

  ```
  # It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
  # below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
  #
  #       /etc/apache2/
  #       |-- apache2.conf
  #       |       `--  ports.conf
  #       |-- mods-enabled
  #       |       |-- *.load
  #       |       `-- *.conf
  #       |-- conf-enabled
  #       |       `-- *.conf
  #       `-- sites-enabled
  #               `-- *.conf

  # Include list of ports to listen on
  Include ports.conf
  ```

To answer with the desired configuration examples:

### Nginx

```
http {
    server {
        listen 192.0.2.1:80;
        listen 192.0.2.2:80;
        listen 192.0.2.3:80;
        listen 192.0.2.1:443 ssl;
        listen 192.0.2.2:443 ssl;
        listen 192.0.2.3:443 ssl;
        . . .
    }
}
```

### Apache

```
Listen 192.0.2.4:80
Listen 192.0.2.5:80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 192.0.2.4:443 https
    Listen 192.0.2.5:443 https
</IfModule>
```